# How to recover the size of a csv file in a batch file?

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have to recover the size of a csv file with a batch file and I tried with this code, but when I echo the size, there is nothing inside the value. Do you have any idea of the problem ? (By the way I am in the good directory, so the path is good and I tried without .\\ and nothing change)

```
for %%I in (.\\Tous_les_Liens.csv) do set size = %%~zI
IF (%size% LEQ 1) (goto reussite) ELSE (goto erreurs)

:reussite
echo Tout est normal

:erreurs
echo Il y a des erreurs sur le site
echo %size%
FOR /F %%i in ('type .\\Tous_les_Liens.csv') do echo %%i
exit 9
```

Comment: why `.\\filename`? and why are you trying to append the same file content onto itself? anyway, this will fall through the `:reussite` label to `:erreurs` as well, put `goto :EOF` after `echo Tout est normal` and you cannot have spaces before and after `=` in a `set` statement.

Comment: The .\\filename is the path to the file but without .\\ nothin change. And the penultimate line is for echo the content of the file

Comment: echo content where? You're echoing the content and redirecting it to itself with `>>`

Comment: ```set size = %%~zI``` should read as ```set size=%%~zI```, or better still ```set "size=%%~zI"```

Comment: Thank you, the problem came for the space before and after ```=``` in the ```set```

Comment: In the last for line i try to echo the content of the csv file

Comment: You've said that already, but why redirect that to the file itself?

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean, I was testing smthg when I send this code on Stackoverflow so I'll change it bcs it's unsense

Comment: I have another problem bcs i want to have the size of the csv file into an int (i try with ```set /a size=%%~zI``` for do this after ```IF (%size% LEQ 1) (goto reussite) ELSE (goto erreurs)``` but it doesn't work do you have any idea ?

Comment: That is because metavariable `%%I` no longer exists after the `for` loop has completed. Set it in the for loop as `for %%I in ("Tous_les_Liens.csv") do set /a size=%%~zI`

Comment: Yeah i did it and that doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work is very broad. What happens?

Comment: The value inside size is not considered as an integer value

Comment: So the if line doesn't work and reussite and erreurs are launch

Comment: paste exactly the line you use to `set /a` the value.

Comment: ```for %%I in (.\\Tous_les_Liens.csv) do set /a size=%%~zI ``` ```IF (%size% LEQ 2) (goto reussite) ELSE (goto erreurs) ```

Comment: The output is : 2
Tout est normal
2
Il y a des erreurs sur le site
2

Comment: That is the label fall through I posted earlier. Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want the first `:label` to call through to the error label. Try this:

```
for %%I in ("Tous_les_Liens.csv") do set /a "size=%%~zI"
IF %size% GTR 1 goto :erreurs

:reussite
echo Tout est normal
goto :EOF

:erreurs
echo Il y a des erreurs sur le site
echo %size%
type "Tous_les_Liens.csv"
exit 9
```

Comment: That is working, the problem came from the end of file command that i didn't use thank you

Comment: Yes. And you do not need the `else` statement either as I demonstrated here. The `type` command is all you need as well without the last `for` loop.